# Running multiple threads in Java to have multiple balls in JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working on an assignment that requires me to multiple balls present within a window. I am quite confused as to how this can be accomplished through multithreading, as I have so far been unable to get multiple threads to run at once.

I am clearly misunderstanding something when it comes to multi-threading. Any advice on where to go from here is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ball extends JPanel 
{
    //height and length of ball panel
   private static final int boxLength = 640;
   private static final int boxHeight = 480;
   
   
   private float ballRad = rndRange(10, 20); //radius of ball
   private float ballXStart = rndRange(1, 640); //Starting locations for ball
   private float ballYStart = rndRange(1, 640); 
   private float ballSpeedX = rndRange(1, 20);   //starting speed for ball
   private float ballSpeedY = rndRange(1, 20);
  
   private static final int updateRate = 30; 
   
  
  
   public ball() 
   {
      
      this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(boxLength, boxHeight));
  
      //thread for ball bouncing
      Thread ballBounce1 = new Thread()
      {
         
         public void run() 
         {

            while (true) 
            {
               ballXStart += ballSpeedX;
               ballYStart += ballSpeedY;

               if (ballXStart - ballRad < 0) 
               {
                  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX; 
                  ballXStart = ballRad; 
               } 
               
               else if (ballXStart + ballRad > boxLength) 
               {
                  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                  ballXStart = boxLength - ballRad;
               }

               if (ballYStart - ballRad < 0) 
               {
                  ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                  ballYStart = ballRad;
               } 
               else if (ballYStart + ballRad > boxHeight)   
               {
                  ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                  ballYStart = boxHeight - ballRad;
               }

               repaint(); 

               try 
               {
                  Thread.sleep(1000 / updateRate);  //thread update in milliseconds
               } 
               catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
         }
      };
      
      Thread ballBounce2 = new Thread()
      {
         
         public void run() 
         {

            while (true) 
            {
               ballXStart += ballSpeedX;
               ballYStart += ballSpeedY;

               if (ballXStart - ballRad < 0) 
               {
                  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX; 
                  ballXStart = ballRad; 
               } 
               
               else if (ballXStart + ballRad > boxLength) 
               {
                  ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                  ballXStart = boxLength - ballRad;
               }

               if (ballYStart - ballRad < 0) 
               {
                  ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                  ballYStart = ballRad;
               } 
               else if (ballYStart + ballRad > boxHeight)   
               {
                  ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
                  ballYStart = boxHeight - ballRad;
               }

               repaint(); 

               try 
               {
                  Thread.sleep(1000 / updateRate);  //thread update in milliseconds
               } 
               catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
         }
      };
            
      ballBounce1.start();  
      ballBounce2.start();
      
      try 
      {
        ballBounce1.join();
        ballBounce2.join();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      
   }
  
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics ballContents) 
   {
      super.paintComponent(ballContents);    

      ballContents.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      ballContents.fillRect(0, 0, boxLength, boxHeight);

      ballContents.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      ballContents.fillOval((int) (ballXStart - ballRad), (int) (ballYStart - ballRad),
            (int)(2 * ballRad), (int)(2 * ballRad));
 
   }
  
   public static int rndRange(int max, int min)
   {
       Random rnd = new Random();
       int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(min+1 - max) + max;
       return rndInt;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
      {
         public void run() 
         {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Ball");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(new ball());
            frame.getContentPane().add(new ball());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Create a java.util.List of Ball instances.  The Ball class is a plain Java getter / setter class with a center java.awt.Point and a radius.  Iterate through the List to move the balls.  Iterate through the List to draw the balls on the drawing JPanel.  One java.swing.Timer to control the animation.

Comment: As @GilbertLeBlanc said there is no need to have multiple threads to manage multiple balls animation, a single Timer can update all objects in the list in a run. Moreover it would be better to calculate the position of each ball as a function of time, instead that using fixed increments, since you cannot rely 100% on the fact that the timer is calling your update function exactly every second.